# Movie about a dystopian society where people are shut in their buildings

Tags: story-identification

There are people living in nice downtown style buildings, connected to the internet with modern amenities. Those buildings are **shut off to the outside world** where the dangerous people live.

Some decent guy in the outside world has an old laptop that he uses to login and communicate with a girl in one of those buildings and eventually he gets in. I think at some point he gets her to venture out of the building...

Comment: Any ideas on the age of the movie?

Answer (score 4):

Aside from being a TV episode not a movie it sounds a lot like season 4 episode 15 of sliders called "Net Worth"

Comment: Perhaps 'Net Worth' is based off of the OP's movie?

Answer (score 3):

I do not know if it was ever made into a movie, but it sounds a lot like `Ora:cle`, from [Kevin O'Donell, Jr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kevin_O%27Donnell,_Jr.).

Answer (score 3):

It could be [*Mindwarp*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0100152/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1).

People live in apartments connected to a VR ideal world but the lead character somehow (can't remember if there was someone who contacted her) leaves the building into a post-apocalyptic world.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFF! There isn't much to go off from the OP but this seems to match decently well.